# What are the user accounts for these extensions and modules?

Tags: smarttarget, ecl, translation-manager

To complement a future post on Tridion features and modules, I'd like to ask for your help gathering user account details for the following:

- **Content Manager**
- **External Content Library** (ECL)
- **Translation Manager**
- **SmartTarget**

For any that you know (you don't have to answer all of them*) answer with:

- **User** (default or typical user, if configurable--e.g. MTSUser)
- **Config** location: [typical configuration path and file]
- Optional: notes on authorization from a user perspective, for example with Translation Manager, users need scope to targets and permissions aren't needed

---

*Feel free to add more features, extensions, or modules to the question. Please upvote useful answers. I started a community wiki as an example answer and to summarize answers, but I'll gladly accept the highest scoring, most comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Example answer format (I'll remove this if someone wants to answer **everything**)*

## Content Manager

- User: `MTSUser`(domain account)
- Config: Create in Windows: `System Tools` > `Local Users and Groups` > `Users`.
- Note: do *not* add as a CMS user. See answers and comments to [Neil's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298426/neil) [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9717166/395495).

Other default [user accounts described in the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B47210C8-4381-4C6E-8E2F-FA03ECC62A51), all start with "tcm" such as `tcmpublisher` and `tcmworkflow`.

## External Content Library (ECL)

- User:
- Config:

## Translation Manager

- User:
- Config:

## SmartTarget (ST)

- Users:

  - (Web service) API: `stuser`
  - (Web service) Deployer Extension: `stdeployer`
  - Fredhopper processes (Query Server and Index Server): `fhuser`
- Config: